# Compatibility of SSD with macbook air

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

does MacBook Air7,2 early 2015 support PCIe Gen 3.0 x4 NVMe1.3

Answer (score 1):

If it is not available by Apple in the initial configuration then it is NOT a supported drive. Your best bet it to try and plug it in and see if it works.